# How could a blockchain based system guarantee the immutability of a block?

Tags: blockchain, immutability

After reading *Grokking Bitcoin* I now have a broad idea of how Bitcoin works, but I still have a doubt that, generally, how a blockchain-based system can guarantee the immutability of a random block? I know every block has a stored hash value of the content of the previous block plus some nonce.

Let's say this blockchain(for simplicity, we use a linked-list style rather than a Merkle tree style) has 1000 blocks, and a hacker just changed the content inside of the 10-th block. Of course, if we recompute the hash of this 10-th block and compare it with the hash stored inside of the 11th block, it will be different, most probably.

My question is, should a blockchain-based system periodically check the hash inside of every block to detect if the content of a block is changed? In this case, if the system does not have a function to periodically recompute the hash of the 10-th block, it will not be able to detect the change, right? In other words, my question is how a blockchain-based system detects the change of a block?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the content of the 10th block you have to find the hash to meet the difficulty for that block. This is called "mining" and it takes time/energy. When you finally found the hash value for that block you can propagate your new block to the blockchain to all the other nodes.

However, they will ignore this block which would create a new branch of the blockchain at the 9th block because it is 991 blocks behind the current blockchain (that's about 7 days behind in the blockchain). The miners will work only on the longest chain for new blocks, not on the most recent received chain. So, your new 10th block will not be saved or used at all. Your effort in calculating the hash is wasted. Furthermore, the original 10th block is still inside the blockchain known by every other node and it has not been changed. You have just mined a different 10th block no other node cares about.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Previously I was thinking the hacker may just change the transactions inside of a block rather than propose a new block and make a fork, but considering each full blockchain node has a complete copy of the chain, this is unrealistic. Based on your explanation I now also understand the 51% attack. Thank you very much!